# Regarding 32 bit .exe vs 64 bit .exe

Tags: c#, .net, performance, performance-testing

Is there a difference in performance of a 32 or 64 bit .exe? or Is it just you want to run your application on whatever platform you want (32 bit processor or 64 bit processor).

I mean I have a console application which is right now producing a 32 bit .exe.
It is performing very slow when it is doing too many calculations which increase as user base increases.

On a high level would I be getting a performance benefit if I change it to 64 bit .exe?

I know I would have to optimize my code to gain best performance.

Comment: If the server/desktops you are going to run the application on is always going to be 64 bit then Yes.

Comment: No, there's no Santa Claus there.  Otherwise trivial to find out by yourself, just remove the jitter forcing.  Right-click your EXE project > Properties > Build tab > Platform target and Prefer 32-bit checkbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not as simple, there are certain difference between the two processor architectures (32 bit and 64 bit). 
Nowadays 64 bit systems are becoming the standard, due to various inherent advantages and their ability to run applications with high memory requirement with ease. In simple words to compare:

- A 64 bit system can handle larger amount of data for processing
- Each process can have much higher allocation of memory on a 64 bit system (theoretically it is `2^32 = 4 GB in 32 bit and 2^64 = 16 Exabytes in 64 bit`). In reality a process is limited by the actual RAM size, In 32 bit default user memory is 2 GB, maximum extensible to  3 GB, remaining for Kernel process. Even in 64 GB, it is not that all OS are capable of mapping that much memory for each process, not sure if any of consumer version even goes up to TB per process
- A 64 bit system has much more scope of hardware optimization
- A 64 bit system can run many more applications simultaneously without leading to Out of memory issues
- Even 64 bit OS are separate to take full benefit of the processor functionalities
- A 32 bit system can normally run on a 64 bit system, in windows using a technology like WOW (Windows on Windows), but vice versa is not feasible. However this running is under constraints, it cannot leverage all benefits of a 64 bit system. These process can be easily identified in the Task Manager as they contain a `*32` along with the name

`Regarding performance, there's no thumb rule but as you would have understood, if a process is slowed down due to lack of memory, there's not enough space in RAM for a process to execute, and it leads to frequent paging in and out of the process, and thus making it relatively slow, when being completely in memory, it would be much faster on a 64 bit system`

Check following links, they have lots of relevant and precise information:

[32 vs 64 bit FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/32-bit-and-64-bit-windows#1TC=windows-7)

[How To Geek - 32 vs 64 bit](http://www.howtogeek.com/56701/htg-explains-whats-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-windows-7/)

[Taking mystery out of 64 bit](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows7/taking-the-mystery-out-of-64-bit-windows)

[Difference between 32 and 64 bit OS](http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/32-bit-64-bit-operating-systems/)

Comment: Please check added more details, it may be useful in understanding the performance comparison between two systems